# Permission denied when chown on elasticsearch data directory in kubernetes statefulset

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, kubernetes

Hoping someone can help me resolve what appears to be a permissions error. I'm trying to start a 3-node elasticsearch cluster using the official elasticsearch docker image. When the container was started I was getting an "access denied" error from elasticsearch on /usr/share/elasticsearch/data/nodes so I tried adding a command to make elasticsearch the owner of /usr/share/elasticsearch/data...but I get these errors when I include the chown command:

```
chown: cannot read directory '/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/lost+found': Permission denied
chown: changing ownership of '/usr/share/elasticsearch/data': Operation not permitted
```

Here is my statefulset yaml file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: esnode
spec:
  serviceName: elasticsearch-transport
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: evo-pro-cluster
    spec:
      initContainers:
      - name: init-sysctl
        image: busybox
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        command: ["sysctl", "-w", "vm.max_map_count=262144"]
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
      containers:
      - name: elasticsearch
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
          capabilities:
            add:
            - IPC_LOCK
            - SYS_RESOURCE
        command: ["/bin/sh"]
        args: ["-c", "chown -R elasticsearch:elasticsearch /usr/share/elasticsearch/data"]
        image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.6.1
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        env:
        - name: "ES_JAVA_OPTS"
          value: "-Xms6g -Xmx6g"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9200
          name: http
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 9300
          name: transport
          protocol: TCP
        volumeMounts:
        - name: storage
          mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
        - name: config
          mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
          subPath: elasticsearch.yml
      volumes:
        - name: config
          configMap:
            name: elasticsearch-config
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: storage
      annotations:
        storageClassName: standard
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 110Gi
```

Comment: I moved the command to init containers and it seems to work:

```
    initContainers:
      - name: init-es-settings
        image: busybox
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
        command: ["sysctl", "-w", "vm.max_map_count=262144"]
        command: ["/bin/sh"]
        args: ["-c", "chown -R 1000:1000 /usr/share/elasticsearch/data"]
        volumeMounts:
        - name: storage
          mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This particular docker image expects the data directory to be writable by uid `2000`. You can tell Kubernetes to chown (sort of) the mount point for your pod by adding [`.spec.securityContext.fsGroup`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/api-reference/v1.6/#podsecuritycontext-v1-core):

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: esnode
spec:
  ...
  securityContext:
    fsGroup: 2000
```

(end of course you can get rid of the chown hack or the initContainer)

> `fsGroup`: integer: A special supplemental group that applies to all containers in a pod. Some volume types allow the Kubelet to change the ownership of that volume to be owned by the pod: 1. The owning GID will be the FSGroup 2. The setgid bit is set (new files created in the volume will be owned by FSGroup) 3. The permission bits are OR'd with rw-rw---- If unset, the Kubelet will not modify the ownership and permissions of any volume.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks Janos.

Comment: I set to 1000...not 2000 though

Comment: tried in `containers:` block , got `error validating data: ValidationError(Deployment.spec.template.spec.containers[0].securityContext): unknown field "fsGroup" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.SecurityContext;`

Comment: tried in between `replicas:` & before `template:`. Got `unknown field "securityContext" in io.k8s.api.extensions.v1beta1.DeploymentSpec`

Comment: would be helpful to check out the `gid` of elasticsearch user first by running a test pod/container using elasticsearch image

`kubectl run elastic-test --rm -it --image=docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.9.2 --command -- id elasticsearch` gave `uid=1000(elasticsearch) gid=1000(elasticsearch) groups=1000(elasticsearch),0(root)`

Comment: Use `id -u user` and `id -g user` to get the user and group ID for `user`. I had to mount to my NFS server to see the user and group IDs I needed to use for my deployment. For what it's worth, you can run a pod or deployment in a specific security context the same way as you did here for the StatefulSet.

Comment: Thank you dude, after 4 hours of searching, I finally found the solution :)