# elasticsearch on kube with persistent volume

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I was trying `elasticsearch` deployment on Kubernetes (EKS) cluster with persistence volume (EBS), refering to https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: elasticsearch
    spec:
      initContainers:
        - name: init-sysctl
          image: busybox
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          command: ["sysctl", "-w", "vm.max_map_count=262144"]
          securityContext:
            privileged: true
      containers:
      - name: elasticsearch
        image: elasticsearch:6.6.1
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
          capabilities:
            add:
              - IPC_LOCK
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9300
          protocol: TCP
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 1
        env:
        - name: CLUSTER_NAME
          value: elasticsearch
        - name: ES_JAVA_OPTS
          value: "-Xms256m -Xmx512m"
        volumeMounts:
          - name: elasticsearch-storage
            mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
      volumes:
      - name: elasticsearch-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: elasticsearch
```

But pod failed with

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
[2019-03-13T18:03:08,459][WARN ][o.e.b.ElasticsearchUncaughtExceptionHandler] [unknown] uncaught exception in thread [main]
org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.StartupException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to create node environment
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:163) ~[elasticsearch-6.6.1.jar:6.6.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:150) ~[elasticsearch-6.6.1.jar:6.6.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:86) ~[elasticsearch-6.6.1.jar:6.6.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:124) ~[elasticsearch-cli-6.6.1.jar:6.6.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90) ~[elasticsearch-cli-6.6.1.jar:6.6.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:116) ~[elasticsearch-6.6.1.jar:6.6.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:93) ~[elasticsearch-6.6.1.jar:6.6.1]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to create node environment
    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:298) ~[elasticsearch-6.6.1.jar:6.6.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:265) ~[elasticsearch-6.6.1.jar:6.6.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$5.<init>(Bootstrap.java:212) ~[elasticsearch-6.6.1.jar:6.6.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:212) ~[elasticsearch-6.6.1.jar:6.6.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:333) ~[elasticsearch-6.6.1.jar:6.6.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:159) ~[elasticsearch-6.6.1.jar:6.6.1]
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data/nodes
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:90) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:116) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.createDirectory(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:385) ~[?:?]
    at java.nio.file.Files.createDirectory(Files.java:689) ~[?:?]
    at java.nio.file.Files.createAndCheckIsDirectory(Files.java:796) ~[?:?]
    at java.nio.file.Files.createDirectories(Files.java:782) ~[?:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.env.NodeEnvironment.lambda$new$0(NodeEnvironment.java:270) ~[elasticsearch-6.6.1.jar:6.6.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.env.NodeEnvironment$NodeLock.<init>(NodeEnvironment.java:203) ~[elasticsearch-6.6.1.jar:6.6.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.env.NodeEnvironment.<init>(NodeEnvironment.java:267) ~[elasticsearch-6.6.1.jar:6.6.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:295) ~[elasticsearch-6.6.1.jar:6.6.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:265) ~[elasticsearch-6.6.1.jar:6.6.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$5.<init>(Bootstrap.java:212) ~[elasticsearch-6.6.1.jar:6.6.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:212) ~[elasticsearch-6.6.1.jar:6.6.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:333) ~[elasticsearch-6.6.1.jar:6.6.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:159) ~[elasticsearch-6.6.1.jar:6.6.1]
    ... 6 more
```

From this [discussion](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elastic-elasticsearch-docker-not-assigning-permissions-to-data-directory-on-run/65812/2), it looks like permission issue on `/usr/share/elasticsearch/data` dir.

following `initContainers` helped to get me around this issue.

```
initContainers:
  - name: init-sysctl
    image: busybox
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    #command: ["sysctl", "-w", "vm.max_map_count=262144"]
    command: ["/bin/sh","-c"]
    args: ["sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144; chown -R 1000:1000 /usr/share/elasticsearch/data"]
    securityContext:
      privileged: true
    volumeMounts:
      - name: elasticsearch-storage
        mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
```

Whats is correct way to fix this issue ?

Comment: It looks like a bug in the docker image , dockerfile , please see the volume instruction and setting permission , and the order of those instructions. related issue:https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/37030

Comment: It looks like in the dockerfile they are settings the user and group for that directory , but then when you run , and mount the volume on that path , those settings are gone and you then need to reset them again

Answer (score 3):

The solution you are using is a workaround , but you can do it a bit kubernetes way is explained here:

[Permission denied when chown on elasticsearch data directory in kubernetes statefulset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46351051/permission-denied-when-chown-on-elasticsearch-data-directory-in-kubernetes-state)

So in your case it should be like:

```
....

spec:
  ...
  securityContext:
    fsGroup: 1000
```

Comment: Got `error validating "qa/elasticsearch.yaml": error validating data: ValidationError(Deployment.spec.template.spec.containers[0].securityContext): unknown field "fsGroup" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.SecurityContext; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false`

Comment: hmm , you put it in wrong place, please see the syntax

Comment: tried after `replicas:` & before `template:`. Got `unknown field "securityContext" in io.k8s.api.extensions.v1beta1.DeploymentSpec`